# How to uninstall pip ipykernel without uninstall ipykernel in Anaconda?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I accidentally did

```
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

But I found later on I should just

```
conda update ipykernel
```

Now I have two jupyter_core,setuptools, requests etc. How to uninstall the redundant packages that I installed via pip. I tried

```
pip uninstall ipykernel
```

and got

```
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (ipykernel) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. 
This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling ipykernel-4.6.1:
  /Users/jan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel-4.6.1-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? n
```

What should I do to undo `install pip ipykernel?` or `pip uninstall ipykernel` without uninstall ipykernel in Anaconda?

Comment: Uninstall them both and just reinstall in conda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without answers, I tried

```
pip uninstall ipykernel
```

and found it removing only the pip installed version one. So I uninstalled it and packages that installed with ipykernel manually. No need to reinstall at all. Anyway, I had to command one by one as I could not find how to uninstall many packages (but not all) in one line command.

Packages from `install pip ipykernel` including ipykernel, tornado, ipython, certifi, traitlets, jupyter_core, setuptools, prompt_toolkit, Pygments, and pyparsing.